# Problems with character sets

Tags: ms-access, special-characters, vba

I have `MS Access 2010` forms linking to a `mySQL5` (utf8) database.

I have the following data stored in a `varchar` field:

```
"Jaros&#322;aw Kot"
```

MS Access is just display this raw, as opposed to converting it to:

```
Jarosław Kot
```

Can anyone offer assistance?

Thanks Paul

Comment: You'd better go through your questions and accept the best answers, because this people wasted their time to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The notation `&#322;` is a character reference in SGML, HTML, and XML. There is in general no reason to expect any software to treat it as anything but a literal of six characters “&”, “#”, etc., unless the software is interpreting the data as SGML, HTML, or XML.

So if you have data stored so that `&#322;` should be interpreted as a character reference, then you should convert the data, statically or dynamically. The specifics depend on what actual data there is—for example, do all the constructs use decimal notation (not hexadecimal), and is it certain that all numbers are to be interpreted as Unicode numbers for characters?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can use [Replace](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php) function:

`Replace("Jaros&#322;aw Kot", "&#322;", "ł")`

Comment: Hello. I'm looking for a reusable function. For example PHP has html_encode() etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your mySQL database character set is effectively set to UTF8 and that all inserts and updates are utf8 compatible (I do not know that much about mySQL, but SQL Server has some specific syntax rules for utf8-compliant data...), you could then convert the available HTML data to plain UTF8 data.

You will not have any problem finding some conversion table ([here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for example), and, if you are lucky, you could even find a conversion function...